# How do I install pthreads-w32 statically in a project built using configure.js and nmake?

Tags: php, windows, visual-c++, pthreads, pthreads-win32

I am building PHP from source code using the Visual C++ 2017 compiler, and it uses configure (`configure.js`) to configure the build, and `nmake` to build.

I've read the documentation on pthreads-w32 (nonportable) and read a lot of answers here, but it didn't help me figure out how to compile the source code of pthreads in projects of this type using `configure.js` by using the `PTW32_STATIC_LIB` flag.

PHP is able to configure flags and connect the necessary `\*.c` files at the right time, and it needs `pthreadVC2.lib`, and I have it. But, according to my assumption, it is this file that needs to be collected separately using this flag, did I understand it correctly?

The `PTW32_STATIC_LIB` flag is already enabled via `configure.js`, however, the original pthreads is not included in PHP and to run it requires `pthreadVC2.dll`.

Thanks in advance for the answers!